# Launch wizard from Active Help page in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm creating an RCP application and wanted to provide documentation using the Eclipse Help Contents (`Help > Help Contents`), I managed to add some pages to it by using the extension point `org.eclipse.help.toc`, this works fine, but I'm interested in providing a link in one of those pages to launch a wizard, I found that Eclipse provides support for this using a feature called [Active Help](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help_content_active.htm?cp=2_0_19_1_1_7).

First, in my html Help page I have imported the `livehelp.js` script:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script language="JavaScript" src="PLUGINS_ROOT/org.eclipse.help/livehelp.js"></script>
<head>
```

Then in the `<body>` I added a link:

```
<a href='javascript:liveAction("com.test.my.plugin", "com.test.my.plugin.actions.TestAction", "")'>Execute action</a>
```

And finally, this my `TestAction` class:

```
public class TestAction implements ILiveHelpAction {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Action executed");
        // code to launch wizard is here
    }

    @Override
    public void setInitializationString(String str) {

    }
}
```

But when the link is clicked the action is not executed, I tried setting a breakpoint in the `run()` method but it is never called, any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. But I think I was doing something wrong: I was copying my plugin manually into eclipse/plugins directory.

I tried with a "correct" plugin distribution mechanisms:

- a feature plugin
- an update site plugin
- a standard installation from within eclipse instance, menu help-> install new software

And now things are working... my action gets called normally..