# Launch action from Active Help page in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have problems in launching a custom action from HTML/Javascript documentation in Eclipse.
The problem is exactly the same as this:

[Launch wizard from Active Help page in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205437/launch-wizard-from-active-help-page-in-eclipse)

so I won't describe it again. 
I have found no solution or hint whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

OK.. I was doing something wrong. 
I was copying my plugin manually into eclipse/plugins directory.

Now I tried with a "correct" plugin distribution mechanisms:

- a feature plugin
- an update site plugin
- a standard installation from within eclipse instance, menu help-> install new software

And now things are working... my action gets called normally..

Comment: ...or copying the plug-in manually into the `dropins` (instead of into the `plugins`) folder.

Comment: So dropins is the right folder to copy plugins manually?? Ok...good to know! :)